# Cannot authenticate on phone

Tags: pokemon-go

I can log into my Pokemon Trainer Club account from my computer, but when I try the same credentials on my phone, it tells me it cannot authenticate. What can I do to get logged in?

Comment: The Pokémon GO servers are having issues atm. Just wait it out and it'll be fine later again.

Answer (score 0):

The pokemon Go servers are down. YOu can keep up to date on their server specific twitter page @PoGoServer